# "Fix similar errors" feature in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

This is a question about Netbeans. In the Tasks panel, can I select some similar errors and fix them all? I remember doing this in eclipse.

For example, I have a lot of warnings about not using String concatenation with a StringBuilder, and Netbeans is capable of fixing those errors replacing the String concatenations with calls to the `StringBuilder.append()` method. It would be nice if I could fix all those errors with just one click.

Comment: You could probably create a macro to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently not aware of anything built into netbeans that does this.

A macro would be best, although good old <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB71#Inspect_And_Refactor